# tabwidget doesnt work mono c#

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-tabhost

tab widget doesnt work. i got this (this is the next statement to execute when this threads returns from the current function)

```
        TabHost mTab = new TabHost(this);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
        i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        mTab.AddTab(mTab.NewTabSpec("tag").SetIndicator("label").SetContent(i));

        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
        i2.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        mTab.AddTab(mTab.NewTabSpec("tag2").SetIndicator("label2").SetContent(i2));

        mTab.CurrentTab = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TabHost is not being set as the contentView. You need to add a tabHost object to your main.xml layout file then reference it like this:

```
TabHost mTab = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
```